# Get difference between dates and format with 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, react-native

ACTUAL TIME IS 2023-02-24T04:34:39.884+05:30
CURRUNT TIME 2023-02-24T10:16:13+05:30
DIFFERANCE B/W TWO DATES 18:18:26

but actual result according to above is 6 hours, so this is wrong time 18:18:26 occur.
How to check formate date also means DD:MM:YY HH:mm:ss can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: you need to share the code which is producing the wrong output so that we can help you to fix it, any way please check if this [helps](https://blog.bitsrc.io/calculate-the-difference-between-two-2-dates-e1d76737c05a)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate number of days between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score -1):

use moment or dayjs to change and update date and time formate according to your requriemnt

yarn add moment || yarn add dayjs

```
  moment().formate('DD:MM:YY HH:mm:ss') // pass 'DD:MM:YY HH:mm:ss' in formate('') to get date in this formate
```

if you have want to formate specific date then pass in moment()

let date = 2023-02-24T04:34:39.884+05:30

```
moment(date).formate('DD:MM:YY HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: [Moment js is dead](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Comment: dayjs is next to it